# Compare large lists and extract missing data

Tags: java, list, collections

I have two very large `ArrayList`, each containing millions of data. I want to filter out data from `List1` which is not present in `List2` and / or vice-versa.

I've tried Apache CollectionUtils, Java 8 stream API without any success.

Java 8 parallel streaming is consuming all the CPU and CollectionUtils keeps on comparing data set without any output.

**POJO Sample**

```
public DataVO {
 private String id;
 private String value;
 ...
 // getters / setters

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = (prime * result) + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
  return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
  ...
  ...
  final DataVO other = (DataVO) obj;
  if (id == null) {
   if (other.id != null) {
    return false;
   }
  }
  else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

hashCode() / equals() can have more fields, for now I've kept it simple.

I also tried spliting `List1` into smaller chunks and then tried comparing against `List2` without any results. I've looked at other questions but none of them have consider extremely large volume.

Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Comment: If you're cross-comparing millions of items in a list it's going to take time, and memory. You might want to put in some sanity-check logging (e.g., print out the current item's index every 100k or something) so you can at least see (a) that it's making any progress, and (b) if/where it's bogging down or if it's just because you have to iterate over multiple lists multiple times. In general, you don't want to do this.

Comment: Hello. Did you use Apache CollectionUtils `substract` or another method ? What was the output ? Does this two list are the result of a database extraction ?

Comment: Have you tried to put first array to the set and then iterate through the second collection and check if the element is in the set ?

Comment: You need to know the runtime complextity of your collections. Finding an object in a List is O(N) , making the whole process O(M*N). Finding an object in a HashSet is O(1). So turn one of the lists (the smallest one) into a HashSet, check if the elements of the other list are present in the Set. That will make the process O(M).

Comment: @JBNizet The list turned into a `HashSet` should be the largest one. Tech Sawi: So you want the intersection of the two lists? What about order? If `list1=[1,2,3,4]` and `list2=[4,3,5,6]`, what should be the output: `[3,4]` or `[]` (empty because if order matters, `[3,4] != [4,3]`?

Comment: Are these arrays sorted? If they are, we would solve the problem with an algorithm which is similar to 'merge sort'.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. I need to extract missing data, order doesn't matter. If list1=[1,2,3,4] and list2=[4,3,5,6] then output should be list=[1,2]. Neither of Apache CollectionUtils `substract` or `removeAll` worked due to size. I'll try `HashSet`, hopefully that would work.

Comment: In the question; you said and/or vice versa. If it is so, then one HashSet is not enough. If your input is not ArrayList don't use it in the first place.

Comment: Usually, the standard collection operations like `removeAll` or `retainAll` should be sufficient here, **iff** you are converting the collections into `Set` instances (e.g. `HashSet`). Unless you explicity want to *avoid* creating a copy of one of the collections, I think that the question is not stated properly. An [MCVE] with auto-generated/dummy data and a dummy `DataVO` class could help to flesh out what the actual question is.

Comment: @Marco13 there is no restriction on copying but the shear size of lists is bit worrisome.

Comment: @halil both inputs are ArrayList, each containing a million+ data. Vice versa could be a requirement but for now List1 is to be compared with List2 and find out what all data is not present in List2. I would have loved to use database but given circumstances that’s not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read big chunks of the `ArrayList` into a `HashSet`, say by 10k elements. Make sure you set the size on the `HashSet` constructor. Then for each chunk call `HashSet#RemoveAll` with the other `ArrayList`. The remaining entries are your answer. Might even parallelise with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
List missing = new ArrayList(); // answer

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); ) {
    int offset = i;
    i += 16 * 1024;
    if (i > list1.size()) i = list1.size();
    Set chunk = new HashSet(list1.subList(offset, i));

    for (int j = list2.size(); --j >= 0; chunk.remove(list2.get(j));
    missing.addAll(chunk);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It's working for my requirement.

Comment: I modified a bit my creating `sub lists` outside but rest of the logic remains same.

Comment: @TechSawi What do you mean by "outside"? Note that the exact sublist changes in each loop iteration...

Comment: @Marco13 I created sub lists separately and them looped through the list to find missing data. Time taken was half.

Comment: Having those sublists externally then you could even go all the way and create a `java.util.concurrent.Future<Set<DataVO>>` for each of them and utilise several cores with a `ThreadPoolExexutor` for maximum performance @Tech Sawi.

Comment: I was a bit surprised by the speedup of the separation. It turns out the HashSet Collection constructor uses an iterator which is quite slow for ArrayList. It'd probably be better to call the constuctor with twice the size [32*1024] and HashSet#add each sublist's ArrayList#get like the #remove is done in the example code.

Comment: @Pascal de Kloe I tried increasing the size of constructor but compared to Sub lists it was still slow. I’ll check my results again though. I haven’t tried ‘Future’, will check that too.